# Ajax Error status giving error 0 while I using Laravel API in Localhost

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.5

I'm doing this totally in localhost. And Creating Laravel API and called them via AJAX. This is my AJAX code:

```
function checkLogin() {
    var objectData = {
        caller_id: document.getElementById('caller_id').value,
        password: document.getElementById('password').value
    };

    var objectDataString = JSON.stringify(objectData);
    console.log(objectDataString);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8000/api/caller/check",
        dataType: "json",
        data: objectDataString,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

And CORS job which is also caused for this Error. But I figured it out. Here is the code in Laravel Framework.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
}
```

This is located at Middleware folder. I cleared the cache as well. Does anyone know how this is caused?

Comment: The error handler has **three** parameters. Post all of them. Any errors in the console on the network tab?

Comment: No Errors at Network tab. All show 200 status.
And
Console Error output:
jqXHR.status= 0
textStatus = 
errorThrown=error
@Andreas

Comment: check whether the JSON coming back from your server is valid. Look in the response tab of the ajax call. Possibly jQuery is failing to parse it.

Comment: I checked my API in postman where I got response. But here I did not find any response of the ajax call.